# Property of int,bool,nsstring,idexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I had declared Property of `int` in the .h class like:

```
@property (nonatomic) int  selectedIndex;
```

The issue is when I switch to another class and come back to my tableview, the value of `selectedIndex` get lost.I want to save the selected value in `selectedIndex`?

Help me guy where I had done mistake in property Declaration?

In the didSelect function I an storing the value:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
     [tableView reloadData];
     myTimeSlot=[timeSlot objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

And in cellForRowatIndexPth I am retrieving It,Like:

```
if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Everything is fine in same class but when I navigate to another class,My value lost....???

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your property declaration as such. You will need to show more code for folk to try to help you. However an obvious guess is you are setting the property on one instance of your class and later unintentionally reading it from a *different* instance and hence getting the unexpected result.

Comment: There's no mistake in the property declaration. You need to show the code which is storing to the property and which is reading it. Also, are you sure you're using the same object in both cases (and your references aren't `nil`)?

Comment: You are not using an accessor but directly setting a variable. You can get things wrong by declaring the variable as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 Will you Explain it more ?? I had synthesize it to active getter setter.

Comment: Write `NSLog(@"Object is %@", self);` in both of the methods above and show what values/addresses are printed.